# sql запрос в базу данных

Tags: php, mysql

Допустим, есть таблица:

```
Число | Ответ
10000 | A
20000 | B
30000 | C
```

Если мое число `15000` - ответ должен быть `A` (от `10000` до `20000`)
Если мое число `20001` - ответ `B`

Каким должен быть запрос в базу?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `Ответ`
FROM `Таблица`
WHERE `Число` < @Число
ORDER BY `Число`DESC
LIMIT 1
```